# $injector error when using angular-bootstrap ($modalInstanceProvider <- $modalInstance)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui, angular-ui-bootstrap

I've been playing around with this bug but I can't seem to figure it out. The problem started when I pushed the angular-bootstrap models I had added to the prod server. The original error was this:

> "AngularJS Error: Unknown provider: aProvider <- a"

I'm pretty sure I was getting that error because my files weren't minifying correctly. So I went through my controllers and found that I wasn't `$injecting $modal` instance into my controllers and that's when I ran into this problem.

Whenever I inject `$modalInstance` into my controller in the minified format I get this error. I am not using the format angular-bootstrap suggests because I have a lot going on and many controllers on the site I'm building so I combined everything into one controller instead of several functions.

My Controller:

```
.controller('CreateGroupCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', '$window', '$cookies', '$modal', '$log', 'FeedService', '$modalInstance', 
function CreateGroupCtrl($scope, $http, $window, $cookies, $modal, $log, $modalInstance, FeedService) {
$scope.createGroupCall = function createGroupCall(teacher, name) {
    if(teacher != null && name != null) {
            FeedService.createGroupCall($cookies.token, $window.sessionStorage.user, teacher, name).success(function(data) {
            console.log('GroupCreated');
        }).error (function(status,data,token) {
            console.log(status);
            console.log(data);
        });
    } else {
        alert("Error!");
    }
}

/***********ANGULAR-UI MODAL CODE**********/
$scope.open = function (size) {
    var modalInstance = $modal.open({
        templateUrl: 'CreateGroupContent.html',
        controller: CreateGroupCtrl,
        size: size
});

modalInstance.result.then(function (selectedItem) {
    $scope.selected = selectedItem;
}, function () {
    $log.info('Modal dismissed at: ' + new Date());
    });
};

$scope.ok = function () {
    $modalInstance.close();
};

$scope.cancel = function () {
    $modalInstance.dismiss('cancel');
};

}]);
```

My Template:

```
<button ng-controller="CreateGroupCtrl" ng-click="open()" type="button" id="creategroup" class="btn ns-btn">
        <img class="ns-add" src="images/createGroup.png">
        <p class="create">Create Group</p>
</button>

<div>
    <script type="text/ng-template" id="CreateGroupContent.html">
        <div class="modal-header">
                <h2 class="modal-title ns-modal-title">Create A Group</h2>
                <button class="ns-modal-close" ng-click="cancel()"><img src="images/xCancel.png"></button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <form class="form-signin" role="form">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control ns-modal-form" placeholder="Teacher" ng-model="create.teacher" required autofocus>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control ns-modal-form" placeholder="Group Name" ng-model="create.name" required>
                </form>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button class="btn ns-modal-add ns-btn" ng-click="createGroupCall(create.teacher, create.name); ok();" type="submit">Create</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </script>
</div>
```

Comment: In the pasted example `'FeedService', '$modalInstance'` are flipped, when you compare dependencies and constructor. Was that a typo in the question?

Comment: no, thats how i had it but i fixed it still gives me an error.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

At first, you need to inject all in its order.

Also, you should inject `$modal` into the controller in which you would like to create your modal view. And the `$modalInstance` can be injected ***ONLY*** into the controller which is used for this `$modal` window. In your case you use the same controller, so you couldn't inject `$modalInstance`

#### Demo: http://plnkr.co/edit/khzNQ0?p=preview

Also, in your case (when you use only 1 controller) - you can pass as object field `scope` which will be used as parent of `$scope` for your modal view. By default it is `$rootScope`, but you can type:

```
$scope.open = function (size) {
    var modalInstance = $modal.open({
        templateUrl: 'CreateGroupContent.html',
        controller: CreateGroupCtrl,
        size: size,
        scope: $scope
});
```

So now your functions `ok()` and `cancel()` will be available in your modal view and modal scope.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your `FeedService` and `$modalInstance` are mixed up. They need to be in the same order.

Comment: i put them in the right order still gives me an error.